# Can a Basilisk control whether or not its gaze will kill?

Tags: harry-potter

Can a Basilisk in the Harry Potter world can turn its killing gaze on and off at will?  Thus allowing it to look at someone it is taking orders from and not harm them or selectively target only non-purebloods.

Comment: Heh, I tried to check for dupes, missed that one

Comment: I wonder if Medusa could do the same, and that whenever she kills herself when looking into a mirror, that's only because she's actively trying to kill someone else

Comment: Sorry your question got closed... :( I didn't realize that someone already asked it, but phrased it differently.

Comment: No biggie, I don't think that one came up when I looked and found the two I had linked in the comments of the other question

Comment: @Forral Okay, thanks! Yeah, when there are so many ways to ask the same question, it can be hard to find duplicates. About actually coming up with an answer, I'll hopefully have an answer up on the other question once I do some more research.